# stencil change @Prop() detection

Tags: angular, stenciljs

How can I detect prop changes in stencil, in angular is something like this:

But I don't know how is in stencil.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-name',
  template: `
      <h2>First name: {{name}} ({{_name}})</h2>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  private _name: string;
  constructor() {}

  get name(): string {
    // transform value for display
    return this._name.toUpperCase();
  }

  @Input()
  set name(name: string) {
    console.log('prev value: ', this._name);
    console.log('got name: ', name);
    this._name = name;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('on init');
    console.log(this._name);
  }
}
```

I need to detect properties changes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`@Watch`](https://stenciljs.com/docs/decorators#watch-decorator) decorator on a method that will trigger when the property changed.

```
@Watch('name') 
onNameChanged(newValue: string, oldValue: string) {
  this._name = newValue;
}
```

> **Note on `@Watch`:** this decorator only trigger on prop changed, it means the `onNameChanged()` method won't be called the first time that prop is set. In order to intercept the first set, you have to use the `componentWillLoad()` hook.
>
> ```
> componentWillLoad(){
>   this.onNameChanged(this.name);
> }
> ```

**Working example:**

```
import { Component, Prop, Watch } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-name'
})
export class ChildComponent {

  private _name: string;

  @Prop() name: string = '';

  @Watch('name')
  onNameChanged(name: string) {
    console.log('prev value: ', this._name);
    console.log('got name: ', name);
    this._name = name.toUpperCase();
  }

  componentWillLoad(){
    this.onNameChanged(this.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (<h2>First name: {this.name} ({this._name})</h2>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really so helpful.

Comment: just work in future prop changes, if you need at the first time, it works with componentWillLoad.

Comment: I believe you are correct, I added a note to reflect that on my answer.